# Is it possible to have unique + null

Tags: mysql, index

I have a need to have a database table that has a column that is either null, or unique values. I know I can control that in code, but is there a way to do that with an index as a backup? Or is that just really bad DB design? :) For example, I don't want to require an email address, but if they do enter one, I don't want to allow duplicates. Easy enough to check with my code, but I would like to configure Mysql to enforce it. Maybe a trigger returning false if the rules are violated?

Comment: A unique index (not primary key) will allow a NULL value, although it isn't great design to rely on (presumably) an exception being thrown from the "insert" statement to check whether the value is unique. If you try to insert a duplicated (non-null) value with this index you will get an error.

Comment: But will it allow multiple nulls? Null is my exception to unique. And I never rely on a database exception, I just want to be sure if some user spoofs my top-level code, they can't screw up the database. :)

Comment: Yes, that's the standard behaviour of `UNIQUE` constarints. They completely ignore `NULL` values, exactly as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for
>   columns that can contain NULL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

It is easily testable, just try to insert multiple NULL values in dummy table.